# Find the upper and lower bounds of a coin weighing problem so that they coincide

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, algorithms, computational-complexity, upper-lower-bounds

We are given $N$ coins which are identical to each other with the exception of only 1 fake coin which is slightly heavier. The problem is to find the heaviest coin. We also have a Balance Scale. One operation is to put a set of coins in the two sides of the scale and the answer of the operation is whether it balances to a certain side.

Find the lower and upper bound for the above problem so that the two bounds coincide.

The classic algorithm that solves the Balance puzzle problem gives the number of weighings in $\log_3(N)$ weighings for $N$ coins so I guess that's an upper bound. How can I find the lower bound for this problem?

Comment: Many variants have been asked, but I cannot find (surprisingly, to me) a duplicate post with a reasonable answer. This is a nice, classic problem. I can't tell from your question if you're looking for an exact number, or an estimate of the complexity? It is straightforward to show that the complexity is at least $\Omega(\log N)$, and also straightforard to come up with an algorithm which takes $O(\log N)$ steps. But I think the straightforward analysis may lead one to believe that $\log_2(N)$ steps are necessary, when in fact roughly $\log_3(N)$ will do.

Comment: The classic algorithm that solves the Balance puzzle problem gives the number of weighings in `log3(2N+1)` weighings for N coins so I guess that's an upper bound. How can I prove that the lower bound is `Ω(logN)` as you claim?

Comment: actually the number of weighings is `log3(N)`

Comment: Come up with an algorithm and prove the bounds on the algorithm.